# Building Linq expressions

Tags: c#, linq

I can **easily** build any linq expression without using `Expression` factory methods. for example:

```
Func<int, string> f = i =>
{
    var result = i.ToString();
    //... rest of the code
    return result;
};

Expression<Func<string>> f2 = () => f(123);
var s = f2.Compile()();
```

What's the advantage of building the expression manually by calling factory methods?

Answer (score 5):

Examples:

- you are building the query based on reflection of a model you don't know about in advance
- you are building the query based on input, i.e. parsing a string `"(a.b + c) * 7"`
- you are composing multiple expressions into a single expression (visitor pattern, maybe)
- you are doing things that can't be validly expressed via lambdas, i.e. statement bodies, member-assignment, etc (which are available in .NET 4.0, but not via the lambda compiler)
- you are using a language/version that doesn't have a lambda compiler
- you want fine-grained control over the lambda construction (i.e. what is a constant, what is captured, etc)
- you just want to learn how it all works

Comment: I'm writing an expression parser. I see compiling to anonymous functions is much simpler than compiling to linq expressions. I want to know which way is better and has more applications?

Comment: @mrtofigh if you are writing a *parser*, then that is presumably executing at runtime, and you have to use `Expression` directly. You can only use lambdas if you are offloading that to the *compiler* (or using `CSharpCodeProvider`). Personally, I'd probably look at `ILGenerator` here, but I am a bit.... fussy.